# Iframe in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How can I pass the data from a controller to a view page thats been loaded via iframe in CodeIgniter?

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some code examples, and an explanation why you are using an iframe (instead of...say, javascript?).  It will help us to better answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iframe src should be the controller function just like u accessing a seperate page

Answer (score 1):

You can also use postmessage.js to manage communication between iframes and host pages. There are both the original [jquery-based version](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/docs/files/jquery-ba-postmessage-js.html) and a [stand-alone version](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2010/01/15/backwards-compatible-postmessage/).

Answer (score 0):

mmm I think what you should do if you want to use an Iframe, is to refresh the page via ajax, sending the values trough the url.

Altough if you are using ajax to refresh, you should do the display of your information with this method as well, instead of the IFRAME.

In any case you could use jquery to refresh your iframe.

you could access the iframe like this:

> $(window.frames['my-iframe'].document)

If you could implement a full jquery solution, instead of this iframe method, It will make your life easier.